# Using { in SQL queries

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

PHPMyAdmin says the following query is not correct because of the { and } usage.

```
UPDATE jos_content 
SET `fulltext` = REPLACE(`fulltext`, 
              'onclick="return hs.expand(this)"',
              'onclick="return hs.expand(this,{slideshowGroup: 'popupimage'})"')
```

What's the right way of putting this query?

And what if I want it to search in the whole db (not just in the jos_content table)?

Comment: Does the syntax highlighting not point out a problem in that query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not incorrect because of the {, it's incorrect because of the unescaped single quotes in 'popupimage' (as you can see from the syntax highlighting here).

Corrected:

```
UPDATE jos_content 
SET `fulltext` = REPLACE(`fulltext`, 
              'onclick="return hs.expand(this)"',
              'onclick="return hs.expand(this,{slideshowGroup: \'popupimage\'})"')
```

Comment: Thanks, and what if I want to make the replace command to work for the whole db (not just the "jos_content" table and the related "fulltext" field)?

Comment: You can't. You'll need to do it manually or write a script to fetch all the tables and columns and do them one by one.